# How to set rails response header as json?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, http-headers, content-type

I am having a javascript plugin that creates a json. I get that that in params on button click.

Originally that plugin creates

```html
{"fields":[{"label":"Test","field_type":"dropdown","required":true,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"value1","checked":false},{"label":"value2","checked":false}],"include_blank_option":false},"cid":"c2"}]}
```

But when i get params later i get

```
{\"fields\":{\"0\":{\"label\":\"Test\",\"field_type\":\"dropdown\",\"required\":\"true\",\"field_options\":{\"options\":{\"0\":{\"label\":\"value1\",\"checked\":\"false\"},\"1\":{\"label\":\"value2\",\"checked\":\"false\"}},\"include_blank_option\":\"false\"}
```

I am not using form so cant set the response to json.. what should i do to get json in params? Plugin creates json objects and array while in params i get objects. Problem is cant set the content type as json, i guess.

Comment: I think that's only what you see in the rails console. It's how the string is output, but that doesn't mean that the escaping slashes are there in  the original string

Comment: Its not about the slashes. Its it converts the array to objects..

Comment: Are you posting the above json to some controller by ajax?

Comment: setting datatype as json. -- sorry i am using ajax

Comment: Write some code where you are getting this json.

Comment: var path = $('#new_form_path').val();
    var token = encodeURIComponent($('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'));
    console.log('token: ' + token);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: path + "?&authenticity_token=" + token,
      data: {form: {title: title, fields: JSON.parse(payload)}},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {
        location.href = msg.redirect_path;
      },
      error: function(msg){
        //console.log(msg);
        var response = JSON.parse(msg.responseText);
        alert(response.error);
      }
    });

  })
});

Comment: even on server it comes as JSON

Processing by Power::FormsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"form"=>{"title"=>"usman", "fields"=>{"fields"=>{"0"=>{"label"=>"Test", "field_type"=>"dropdown", "required"=>"true", "field_options"=>{"options"=>{"0"=>{"label"=>"value1", "checked"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"label"=>"value2", "checked"=>"false"}}, "include_blank_option"=>"false"}, "cid"=>"c2"}}}}, "authenticity_token"=>"o2xQqMNPLqFyVqbqw78i5xvF4qherpU1SDuYnloBfEs="}

Comment: ok, you are getting the error in parsing the above json at controller level?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93672/discussion-between-chakreshwar-sharma-and-user986508).

Comment: no, my original json which plugin created and i output on console is

{"fields":[{"label":"Test","field_type":"dropdown","required":true,"field_options":{"options":[{"label":"value1","checked":false},{"label":"value2","checked":false}],"include_blank_option":false},"cid":"c2"}]}
later when i get data on server i get {\"fields\":{\"0\":{\"label\":\"Test\",\"field_type\":\"dropdown\",\"required\":\"true\",\"field_options\":{\"options\":{\"0\":{\"label\":\"value1\",\"checked\":\"false\"},\"1\":{\"label\":\"value2\",\"checked\":\"false\"}},\"include_blank_option\":\"false\"}
headers i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code in the ajax:

data: payload,